# How to pull relative date/time using getdate in SQL whereclause

Tags: sql, where-clause, getdate

I have a need to pull data from a previous full calendar day. I am using:

`'(authdate >=''' + formatdatetime('MM/DD/YYYY',getdate-2) +''') and (authdate <=''' + formatdatetime('MM/DD/YYYY',getdate-1) +''')`

However since it is using EST and client is in CST, it is pulling an hour off of what I need. How do I modify this getdate to give me >=47 hours ago and <=23 hours ago ?

Comment: Use DateAdd instead of just doing getdate()-1  and use HOURS instead of days with DateAdd and use 25 hours.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product and date/time functions are quite vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)